# Compressing MP4 files

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, compression, mp4

I have used FFMPEG to convert JPG files to a MP4 file.  Are they any compression techniques/flags/settings/switches i can use to further reduce the size of this MP4 files. I had used gZIP to compress the bytes of this files but it actually resulted in a bigger file.

I am using C#

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MP4 is a container format. Depending on your ffmpeg configuration ffmpeg will either use the encoder `mpeg4` for MPEG-4 Part 2 video or `libx264` for H.264 video.

---

## `mpeg4`

Rate control methods include `-qscale:v` and `-b:v`. These are mutually exclusive so you should use one or the other.

### `-qscale:v`

Sets a constant quantizer, but general users can just think "constant quality". Effective range is 2-31 where 2 is highest quality.

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v mpeg4 -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:v 4 -qscale:a 5 out.mp4
```

### `-b:v`

Allows a video bitrate to be applied. Can be used to target a specific output file size (filesize = duration x bitrate).

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v mpeg4 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:v 512k -b:a 128k out.mp4
```

#### Also see:

- [Xvid / DivX / MPEG-4 Part 2 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20encode%20Xvid%20/%20DivX%20video%20with%20ffmpeg)
- [MP3 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20%28Variable%20Bit%20Rate%29%20mp3%20audio)

---

## libx264

Rate control methods include `-crf`, `-b:v`, and `-qp`, but for the vast majority of users `-qp` can be ignored.

### `-crf`

Constant Rate Factor. Think of it as a "smart" version of `-qscale:v`. Range is logarithmic 0-51. 0 is lossless (big files), ~18 is roughly visually lossless, 23 is default, and 51 is worst quality.

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -codec:a libfdk_aac -vbr 5 output.mp4
```

### `-b:v`

Allows a video bitrate to be applied. Can be used to target a specific output file size (filesize = duration x bitrate). Two-pass example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input -pass 1 -codec:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 800k -an -f mp4 /dev/null
ffmpeg -y -i input -pass 2 -codec:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 800k -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

#### Also see:

- [x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide)
- [CRF Guide (Constant Rate Factor in x264)](http://slhck.info/crf.html)

Answer (score -1):

Compressing an already compressed file usually doesn't make much difference (and it can result in a bigger file).

So if you want a smaller file, I suggest you to change the compression quality of the `mp4` file (whatever technique you are using I think you have this option).

If you are using the command line tool, you can play with the video bitrate to reduce the size of your file:

```
ffmpeg -f your_image_files*.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1200kb your_video.mp4
```

just replace `1200kb` with a lower value and your file size will be smaller

If you want to do it all in C#, and see the encoding progression, you can use this .Net wrapper for ffmpeg:
http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I agree with you.  Do you know what those compression qualities are?  I have found one thing though... if I convert JPGs to flv and call FFMPEG again to convert to MP4 then it does actually compress quite a bit. I have 2 make 2 passes though (calling ffmpeg).  Is there a way to use 'PIPE' - as u would in unix/linux?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about "PIPE" (not a linux user), about the compression quality it depends on the compression method, but it is usually a number between 0 and 100 where 100 is uncompressed, and 0 is unwatchable, could you post your code please? it would be easier that way

Comment: hi,  sorry i thought i had replied.. this is what i am using to convert to flv Arguments {sudo} = @" -f image2 -r " + _fps + " -i  + _path + @"\img%05d.jpg " + _ratio + " -y " +  _fileToUse..flv

Comment: This command is not valid. `-f your_image_files*.jpg` is not an actual option and `-b` is ambiguous and should be changed to `-b:v`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard actually I think this should work, I saw the command line options on a well-known french website (that's why I didn't give the link, it's in french), but I didn't test it, anyway +1 for your answer you give more information in it